# Report Viewer or Gridview/Datalist/Repeater

Tags: .net, asp.net, crystal-reports, report, reportviewer

I want to display data in format

```
Store Name
Department1
User1 2 3 5 6
User2 2 3 5 6
User3 2 3 5 6
User4 2 3 5 6

Department2
User1 2 3 5 6
User2 2 3 5 6
User3 2 3 5 6
User4 2 3 5 6

Store Name1
Department1
User1 2 3 5 6
User2 2 3 5 6
User3 2 3 5 6
User4 2 3 5 6

Department2
User1 2 3 5 6
User2 2 3 5 6
User3 2 3 5 6
User4 2 3 5 6
```

WHich control is best way to display data in above format.
With gridview i have to get each department for given store merge it and show data.
Note: My columns are dynamic

Comment: Yeah but with crystal, you have to gouge out your eyes with a fork and sacrifice cats to Xa-Mul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [nested Repeater controls](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/MasterDetailedDisplay11242005064831AM/MasterDetailedDisplay.aspx)?

Comment: my columns are dynamic how can i bind them to item template?

Comment: You could add columns dynamically to the Repeater, or just use a single column and format your data with HTML (a table, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested DataList control to get this type of output.
For that you have to take two datalist 
Fist one will hold your master data and second one will repeat your data.You have to trap DataList.ItemDataBound Event of first datalist and then find value of id and bind another datalist to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create user control, which displays

```
Department2
User1 2 3 5 6
User2 2 3 5 6
User3 2 3 5 6
User4 2 3 5 6
```

Then create a list of controls and add them to a panel or some container, which has verticla scroll bar.